# RequestCharge on DocumentDb aggregate operation

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to get the RequestCharge when performing a linq count query against documentDb?
Eg sample linq query

```
   count = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionUri, DefaultOptions)
       .Where(f => f.LastName == "Andersen")
       .Count();
```

Thanks

Donal

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the RequestCharge when performing a linq count query against documentDb?

If you want to use linq count query against documentDb, you need to invoke ToList method before Count method.

```
.ToList().Count();
```

It will send multi query to documentDb server and get all the documents back. Here are the request list I found in Fiddler when I invoke ToList().Count(). There are only 2 documents in my collection, so 2 /dbs/ToDoList/colls/Items requests are sent.

[image]

It is equal to following code and RequestCharges can be add together using following code.

```
IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionUri, DefaultOptions)
    .Where(f => f.LastName == "Andersen")
    .AsDocumentQuery();

List<T> results = new List<T>();
double sumRequestCharges = 0;
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<T> queryResult = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
    sumRequestCharges += queryResult.RequestCharge;
    results.AddRange(queryResult);
}
```

If you just need to query the count of your document, we suggest you use a sql query instead of .ToList method. It will not send multi requests to documentDb server and save lots of time. Code below is for your reference.

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<object>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT count(c.id) FROM c")).AsDocumentQuery();
FeedResponse <object> queryResult = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<object>();
double requestCharge = queryResult.RequestCharge;
```

Comment: Thanks Amor I will play with the sql select query and see what that produces. Note that the document db query samples that I was working off do not use the ToList method!

Comment: It will throw a exception if I call Count method directly. If it works on your side, you could check how many requests are sent when you invoke Count method using Fiddler.

Comment: Hi Amor, see this link for the 3 calls the DocumentClient makes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590614/documentdb-query-that-expects-full-results-from-aggregate-functions-is-not-sup

Comment: What is your issue now about this topic? If this issue is solved, We will focuse on the new thread you post.

Comment: Sorry Amor, link was to show the requests the DocumentClient makes. Are you seeing the same when you call .Count() or .CountAsync() directly? Very weird that you are getting an exception. What version of DocumentDb package u on - I am on 1.14.1.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your comment. I was using 1.10.0. After updated to 1.14.1. I can use .count() method directly. It did the same thing as I described in my reply. It will send multi requests to DocumentDb server to get each document. To get the documents count, I suggest you use the SQL query mentioned in my reply.