# DocumentDb - Query that expects full results from aggregate functions is not supported

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I issue a linq count against DocumentDb.
The first POST web request results in a 400 Bad request

Request json:

```
{"query":"SELECT VALUE Count(1) FROM root 
    WHERE ((((root[\"docType\"] = \"Whatever\") 
    AND (root[\"field1\"] = false)) 
    AND (root[\"field2\"] = true)) 
    AND (root[\"field3\"] = 1)) "}
```

Message:
    Query that expects full results from aggregate functions is not supported

This is followed by a GET partition key ranges.

Then another POST web request for the count query which works:

Request json:

```
{"query":"SELECT VALUE [{\"item\": Count(1)}]\r\nFROM root\r\n
    WHERE ((((root[\"docType\"] = \"Whatever\") 
    AND (root[\"field1\"] = false)) 
    AND (root[\"field2\"] = true)) 
    AND (root[\"field3\"] = 1))"}
```

Am I doing something wrong/silly here or is this expected behaviour for documentDb.

Thanks

Donal

Answer (score 0):

> Query that expects full results from aggregate functions is not supported

I do a test and same error "***Query that expects full results from aggregate functions is not supported***" appears on my side if `x-ms-documentdb-query-iscontinuationexpected` request header is set to false.

[image]

Set `x-ms-documentdb-query-iscontinuationexpected` request header to True, and request is ***ok***.

[image]

Please capture your request and check the actual value of `x-ms-documentdb-query-iscontinuationexpected` request header.

Comment: Hi Fred,

I forgot to mention I am using the DocumentClient for creating the query and not me making REST calls directly. Code roughly is:

 var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyType>( collectionUri );
  .Where( doc => doc.field1 == "MyTypeName" );
 int count = await query.CountAsync() ;


I checked the headers and x-ms-documentdb-query-iscontinuationexpected is False for the first call.

On the second call that header is not specified but the x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid is specified which I am guessing comes from the call after first one.

Thanks, Donal